# php code saving a file in hosting server

Tags: php

when i use below code to save an image it saves perfectly

its a part of a script..and i face only problem here 
i think its due to proxy use..
bt i have to use proxy in this script so cant remove that
bt plz need a correct answer

here is without proxy part of script

```
if(preg_match_all('/unsanswerit.php(.*?)"/i',$html, $matches))
{
    $img="".$url."/unsanswerit.php".$matches[1][3]."";
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $img);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);

    $abc=curl_exec($ch);
    $name=rand(0, 999999);
    $path='img/'.$name.'.png';

    $fh = fopen($path, "x");
    fwrite($fh, $abc);
    fclose($fh);

    $st=file_get_contents($path);

    $image=imagecreatefromstring($st);
    $anf= img2txt($image);
    imagedestroy($image);
}
```

and here is  part of script with proxy

```
if(preg_match_all('/unsanswerit.php(.*?)"/i',$html, $matches))
{
    $img="".$url."/unsanswerit.php".$matches[1][3]."";
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $img);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, 'HTTP');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);

    $abc=curl_exec($ch);
    $name=rand(0, 999999);
    $path='img/'.$name.'.png';

    $fh = fopen($path, "x");
    fwrite($fh, $abc);
    fclose($fh);

    $st=file_get_contents($path);

    $image=imagecreatefromstring($st);
    $anf= img2txt($image);
    imagedestroy($image);   
}
```

Comment: What error do you get with proxy? You may need to provide username and password for that proxy

Answer (score 0):

ok guys i have found the solution
its header problem
header should  be false when saving image via curl exe